# How to make a Google Classroom bot without the use of Google API?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am interested in writing a weather bot for a Google Classroom.
I'm able to get the weather info from a website using bs4, but can't find a solution for how to make the bot post something in Google Classroom.
The Google API has way too much stuff included.
The bot has to be in Python, as it is the only language I know well. My final question is:
Is there a library that can post to Google Classroom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some examples of Google classroom bots that use mainly web automation, like [here](https://dev.to/manitej/i-made-a-bot-to-automate-my-online-classes-24j7). However, API is probably your best bet, since that way you don't need to care about sudden changes in format or things like that.